# Precise terms for "Sachebene", "Implikationsebene" and "Textebene"

Tags: grammar, expression

To begin with, I just "invented" these three expressions, maybe an example helps:

*"Er erledigte seinen Auftrag und entsorgte seine Waffe. Dann stieg er in seinen Wagen. Er fuhr davon."*

1. So the "**Sachebene**" is the layer of meaning directly expressed by
   what is written down. Here it would be: A man just accomplished a
   mission, got rid of his weapon and drove away.
2. The "**Implikationsebene**" would reveal that he is a killer who did 
   his job and now he has to escape.
3. The "**Textebene**" implies some kind of hectic activity is going on
   here because of the short, staccato-like sentences (couldn't think
   of a better example—I hope everybody knows what I mean by that)

My question: *Do proper expressions exist for these three layers of meaning?* (Doesn't matter whether they are English or German) I guess the three terms I just made up (except Sachebene—this is from [Schulz von Thun's communication square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-sides_model)) are not widely accepted...

Answer (score 1):

The expressions you are looking for depend on the [model of communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Models_of_communication) you are trying to adapt with this interesting trinominal approach. I do not know if they exist in the context you have outlined above, as I am not a communication scientist.

Nevertheless let me give you my laymans view on the usage of the suffix *"[-ebene](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/-ebene)"* in general.

Whenever this suffix is used we do so to describe a common level. This is mostly done for institutions or for people who are members of a circle:

> *Vorstandsebene*, *Bundesebene*

In analogy to this we also use *"Ebene"* figuratively for a set of 
attributes sharing the same level:

> *auf gedanklicher Ebene*, *auf zellulärer Ebene*.

The usage of *"-ebene"* as as **suffix** in newly made up technical terms is possible and can be understood. As these terms are new they may need an explanation however. The figurative *"Ebene"* however is mostly not used as composite/suffix but is kept as a separate noun with an added adjective. For your examples this would then be:

> *"die sachliche Ebene"*, *"die implizite Ebene"*, *"die textliche Ebene"*

Having said this, I still believe it is perfectly fine to make up new composites with existing words, as they are likely understood, at least from experts on that topic.

Comment: Thank you very much for this interesting link—[Pragmatics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics) seems to be the best choice for the "Implikationsebene". Although concerning the suffix "-ebene" I'm afraid I have to disagree (in this special case): Schulz von Thun, for example, (apparently a native speaker) uses "Sachebene" and "Beziehungsebene" in his [communication square theory](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vier-Seiten-Modell).